# How to properly harden/isolate Chromium snap?

Tags: 22.04, security, snap, chromium, snap-store

I want to harden my Chromium snap, to make it more isolated. I disabled the access for home and system files via the Ubuntu Sofwtare permissions tab. Let's say I want to download images from Unsplash. When I click download button it blocks it with 'Failed - Insufficient permissions'. However, if I just click with right button 'Save image as' I can save it wherever I want. Why is still possible?

Also, should I disconnect/disable chromium:x11 connection, my system is on Wayland?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Snap s by design are quite hardened in the first place, that is the whole point.

Comment: @David, Version 22.04.1

Comment: Does it save to the same location? Does it save to your user's home directory or to the snap directory?

Comment: If it gives you full access, I would file this as a bug report. Not sure if this is a bug related to snap or the chromium snap package in particular. It seems like this would be a bug with snap itself because if chromium can bypass it, then other apps can bypass the permissions as well.